# How to distinguish between VS build and csc.exe build?

Tags: c#

We have two ways to run tests on our product. One is local (using `MsTest` and VS) and the other is using a distant machine (let's call it M). When uploading the code to M, M uses a batch script to generate configuration classes from xml files (which are kept in M) and builds the product using csc.exe. When running tests from the local machine, the xml files aren't used, instead the configuration is taken from in memory classes. This means that we have to make changes to the code each time depending on where we want to run the tests - inherit from different configuration classes (in memory configuration class or external configuration class).

Therefore, is there any way to know at run time if the SW was built using VS or a `.cmd` script?

Comment: It is certainly best to nominate M for early retirement.  Particularly so if the guy that did this isn't around anymore and/or nobody can understand his handiwork.  Use MSBuild.exe instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different build configuration from VS and from the script and so you can do something like this from your code:

```
public bool IsDebugBuild
{
    get
    {
    #if DEBUG
        return true;
    #else
        return false;
    #endif
    }
}
```

Just define your own configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an "automatic" way to discern between the builds as the VS build also uses csc.exe internally.

But you could introduce a compile-time constant that you define only when building in the batch script, e.g.:

```
internal static class BuildInfo
{
    internal static bool BuiltByBatchScript
    {
        get
        {
#if BATCH_BUILD
            return true;
#else
            return false;
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

When calling csc.exe in your batch script, add the following parameter: `/define:BATCH_BUILD`